# Sql semelhante ao PROCV do Excel

Tags: sql

No excel existe a função PROCV, aonde eu consigo obter valores próximos comparando colunas.

Ex.:

```
 A            B
Nome         Dinheiro
Maria        200
João         1000

D                  E          F
Categoria          Min        Max
Médio              0          200
Alto               201        1000
```

Se eu usar chamar PROCV(B2,E:F,1,0), ele me retornaria o valor mais próximo entre Min,Max no caso o resultado seria "Alto".

Existe algo semelhante em Sql, sem ser o BETWEEN?

Answer (score -2):

SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name;

Comment: Olá, Emerson. Sem bem-vindo. Desenvolva mais a sua resposta. Explique, por exemplo, como funciona a sua solução. Dessa forma, sua resposta será mais útil para o(a) autor(a) e para quem mais a encontrar.